# Accessing map<int,int> with `[]`

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm relatively new to c++ and I came across a piece of code and I can't quite understand it. I have the following uninitialized map

```
map<int,int> fq
```

and the following `int` variables:

```
int ans=0
int sum=-1
```

and the following code is what I what I'm having trouble with:

```
++fq[sum]
sum*=2
ans+=fq[-sum]
```

Do keys get assigned by default somehow? My guess is that

```
++fq[sum] sets key:1 to -1 and key:2 to -2 and so on...
```

but I have no idea how `ans+=fq[-sum]` works. Does it add the `key` and add it to `ans`?

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky, but have you considered running that code through a C++ compiler and observing the output? That would probably clue you in to what was happening, quicker than asking a question here. Knowing what you observed through the debugger may help an answerable explain what you're unsure about

Comment: @Tas With C++ you have to be careful, because you might be doing something that's implementation-specific, or which results in undefined behavior, but still gives back nice results. Even with the observed behavior, you might wonder whether the behavior was guaranteed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the C++ `std::map` type, if you look up a nonexistent key with the selection operator (`operator []`), the map will automatically insert a new key/value pair for you. The value associated with the key will be the default value associated with the value type. For `int`s, that's 0, so you can rely on the `std::map` putting in the value 0 if you look up something that isn't there.

For example, if you write

```
++fq[sum];
```

and `sum` isn't a key in `fq`, the following things will happen:

- The map will insert `sum` as a key into the map with value 0.
- The map then returns a reference to the newly-created 0 value.
- That value gets incremented.

The net effect is that `fq[sum]` ends up being 1. This is portable behavior and you can rely on it working this way across different systems.